# junit system property with ant

Tags: ant, properties, junit, system

I have a problem with my ant script!
In my jUnit test I have to set a String with System.getProperty.
Everything works fine when i use eclipse and vm arguments but with the ant script i am not able to pass the system properties...

Here my ant snippet:

```
<junit fork="yes"  haltonfailure="false" showoutput="true">
    <sysproperty key="sdkpath" value="some path"/>          

    or
    <jvmarg value="-Dsdk_path=/some path/"/>

        <batchtest fork="false"  todir="${execution.home}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/src">
                <include name="**/**Test*.java" />
                <exclude name="**/MonkeyTest.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        </junit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <batchtest fork="false"  todir="${execution.home}">
```

to

```
 <batchtest todir="${execution.home}">
```

Comment: thats strange. I did that change and it worked at my end. Can you please check if you are able to read value the other system properties (eg. java.version) in your test case.